# Cannot Bind FlowDocument to RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Here is my Xaml for RichTextBox

```xml
<RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="359,194,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" x:Name="missingVariablesRichTextBox" >
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Here is my `FlowDocument` from CodeBehind. Note message builder is a stringbuilder variable that has some string contents in it.

```cs
FlowDocument missingVariablesDoc = new FlowDocument();
missingVariablesDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(messageBuilder.ToString())));
missingVariablesRichTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
missingVariablesRichTextBox.DataContext=missingVariablesDoc;
```

When I run the application I can't see anything in the `RichTextBox`. What am I missing in the XAML
databinding?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a FlowDocument in code behind you certainly want to assign it to the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) property of the RichTextBox:

```
missingVariablesRichTextBox.Document = missingVariablesDoc;
```

Of course this replaces the FlowDocument assigned in XAML.

Comment: That was quick and superb. Thank you very much Clemens